# Change random ID in mysqli database every time the progress tag reaches 100

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

So I am trying to make a random generated ID to display my monster in PHP. That part I have working so long as the page refreshes. What I need is every time my progress tags value on slayer reaches 100, my query randomly chooses another monster to display. Then when it reaches a hundred: it does the same thing.  I'm making a game that is a clone based off of progress quest (just google it you'll find it). Where the user doesn't have to do anything, but let the game run itself. All the files will be stored as the user name on the server I have that running, and also creating the character. This is the only part so far that I am stuck on. Now I know that you can't imbed PHP code in javascript. I forget where I saw an example that you can add the script tag as a string in PHP. I tried that, and it did not work. I know this might be possible using the microtime function in PHP, or if I could install EvTimer, which I'm not allowed to install on the server.
Here is my php code:

```
$loadCharacter = file("gameSaves/".$user.".txt"); ?>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/game.css" />
<script src="javascript/questingGame.js">
</script>
<form>
    <div id="gameAround">
        <div id="save">
            <button type="button" id="btnSave">Save Game</button>
            <button type="button" id="close">[x]</button>
        </div>
        <div id="character">
            <div>
                <label id="lblName">Name:</label>&nbsp;
                <label>
                    <?php echo $loadCharacter[1];?>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblClass">
                    <?php echo $loadCharacter[2]; ?>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblCharacter">
                    <?php echo $loadCharacter[3]; ?>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblLvl">lvl:</label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="stats">
            <div>
                <label id="lblStr">str:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="str" name="str" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[4]; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblCon">con:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="con" name="con" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[5]; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblDex">dex:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="dex" name="dex" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[6]; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblIntele">int:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="intele" name="intele" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[7]; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblWis">wis:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="wis" name="wis" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[8]; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblCha">cha:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="cha" name="cha" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[9]; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblLuk">Luck:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="luk" name="luk" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[10]; ?>" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="">
            <div>
                <label id="lblExp">exp:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="exp" name="exp" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[12]; ?>" hidden />
            </div>
            <div id="expBar">
                <progress id="prgExp" value="0" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="power">
            <div>
                <label id="lblHp">hp:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="hp" name="hp" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[13]; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <label id="lblMp">mp:</label>&nbsp;
                <input type="text" id="mp" name="mp" readonly="readonly" value="<?php echo $loadCharacter[14]; ?>" />
            </div>
            <div id="slayerBar">
                <div>
<?php
  //$random = rand(150, $enemies["monster_ID"]);
  //$slayerValue = "<script>document.getElementById("+"prgSlayer"+").value;</script>";
  /*do{
  $enemie = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM monsters ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8 ");
  $enemies = mysqli_fetch_assoc($enemie);
  echo "Slaying: " . $enemies["monster_Name"];
  }while($enemies["monster_ID"] != 10);*/
?>
                </div>
                <progress id="prgSlayer" value="0" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
            <div id="itemBar">
                <progress id="prgEcum" value="0" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
            <div id="questBar">
                <progress id="prgQuest" value="0" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
            <div id="plotBar">
                <progress id="prgPlot" value="0" max="100"></progress>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
<?php
    include "htmlCbody.php";
?>
<?php
    include "close_html.php";
?>
```

And my javascript:

```
setTimeout(killMonster, 50);
var i = 0;
window.onload = function() {
  setInterval(killMonster, 50);
}
function killMonster() {
  let slayer = document.getElementById("prgSlayer");
  if (i >= 100 && slayer.value >= 100) {
    i = 0;
    slayer.value = i;
    exp();
    loot();
    quest();
    plot();
  } else {
    i++;
    slayer.value++;
    console.log(slayer.value);
  }
}

function exp() {
  let gainExp = document.getElementById("prgExp");
  let txtLvl = document.getElementById("lvl");
  if (gainExp.value >= 100) {
    gainExp.value = 0;
    txtLvl.value++;
  } else {
    gainExp.value += 0.25;
  }
}

function loot() {
  let item = document.getElementById("prgEcum");
  if (item.value >= 100) {
    item.value = 0;
  } else {
    item.value++;
  }
}

function quest() {
  let quest = document.getElementById("prgQuest");
  if (quest.value >= 100) {
    quest.value = 0;
  } else {
    quest.value += 0.025;
  }
}

function plot() {
  let act = document.getElementById("prgPlot");
  if (act.value >= 100) {
    act.value = 0;
  } else {
    act.value += 0.005;
  }
}
```

Comment: So you want this to happen without a page refresh? In that case, you're looking for AJAX to post your JavaScript value to the server-side script.

Comment: it's very easy to get hacked if you do it all on the client side.